# last kde update 5.20.5 the “add network folder” icon disappeared from the network folder; how to retrieve this icon again

Tags: linux, kde-plasma-5

after the last KDE update 5.20.5 the "add network folder" icon disappeared from the network folder; i don't know is that from the update or i accidentally deleted it. please any one can help me to retrieve this icon again.

Comment: What version of Linux?  Try reinstalling KDE.  Enter a TTY ( Ctrl + Alt + F1 ) and log in there. Run sudo apt-get install --reinstall kubuntu-desktop kde-* || sudo apt-get install -f and KDE should start. You'll have to be connected to the internet for this to work   https://askubuntu.com/questions/761801/kubuntu-16-04-plasma-can-not-start-after-fresh-install

Comment: i am using kde neon ; i think reinstalling kde is not good solution for just missing icon